# AutoMapper Error - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: automapper

Models:

```
public class CredentialAPIModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CredentialEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

my mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CredentialEntity, CredentialAPIModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<CredentialAPIModel, CredentialEntity>();
```

And this is where it fails:

```
public LoginAPIResponse Login(CredentialAPIModel credentials)
{
    CredentialEntity credentialEntity = Mapper.Map<CredentialAPIModel, CredentialEntity>(credentials);

    LoginResponse appSecurityResponse = BO.Login(credentialEntity);

    .
    .
    .       
}
```

I get this:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
CredentialAPIModel -> CredentialEntity
FMG.WebServiceAPI.Models.AppSecurity.Models.CredentialAPIModel -> FMG.Entities.AppSecurity.Entities.CredentialEntity

Destination path:
CredentialEntity

Source value:
FMG.WebServiceAPI.Models.AppSecurity.Models.CredentialAPIModel
```

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() does not find any errors.

Anyone see what's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint for your `Mapper.CreateMap` statements? I'm not seeing any obvious flaws in your code, but you don't say where your `Mapper.CreateMap` statements are being called from. Perhaps they are never being called?

Comment: How do you bootstrap Automapper?